# Apply color on absolute border

Tags: html, css

How can i apply a color to the following image (currently is white, not sure how i change it)?

[Without Background Color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2piA9.png)

This is the css

```
.carousel-inner:after {
    right: 0px;
    border-right: 100vw solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 0px solid white;
}
```

If i try to add a background color, it is applied like here:

[With Background Color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7GBX.png)

```
.carousel-inner:before, .carousel-inner:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    border-top: 123px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 9;
    z-index: 0;
    /* background: red; */
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: need html as well

Comment: show us a snippet that could produce the same issue in the screenshot

Comment: Remove the `border` properties from `.carousel-inner:after` or change the colour to what ever value you need it to be (transparent or another colour).

Answer (score 0):

In those cases you manipulate "background color" by changing border color. Can you try to edit this:

```
.carousel-inner:after {
    right: 0px;
    border-right: 100vw solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 0px solid white;
}
```

and replace `#ffffff` and `white` with your desired color?